# VoIP App using Sailfin

Tags: hardware, voip, sip

I'm looking at developing a VoIP application running on Sailfin (https://sailfin.dev.java.net/).

I have the server up and running and a sample app installed. What I want to be able to do is:

Receive calls from my landline in my VoIP application. 
Make calls from the application to other numbers in the PSTN.

The part I'm not sure about is what hardware do I need between the landline jack and my dev box?

Thanks!

Comment: what are you goin to do is beyong the capability of sailfin..What you need to have is a PSTN gateway. Sailfin is just a SIP application. From what I know, sailfin is not capable to do that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) and hardware used to support it.